# Store comparison in variable (or execute comparison when it's given as an string)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, call

I'd like to know if the super-powerful python allows to store a comparison in a variable or, if not, if it's possible calling/executing a comparison when given as an string ("==" or "!=")

I want to allow the users of my program the chance of giving a comparison in an string.

For instance, let's say I have a list of... "products" and the user wants to select the products whose manufacturer is "foo". He could would input something like:
*Product.manufacturer == "foo"*
and if the user wants the products whose manufacturer is not "bar" he would input *Product.manufacturer != "bar"*

If the user inputs that line as an string, I create a tree with an structure like:

```
            !=
         /     \
manufacturer   bar
```

I'd like to allow that comparison to run properly, but I don't know how to make it happen if *!=* is an string.

The "manufacturer" field is a property, so I can properly get it from the *Product* class and store it (as a property) in the leaf, and well... "bar" is just an string. I'd like to know if I can something similar to what I do with "manufacturer": storing it with a 'callable" (kind of) thing: the property with the comparator: *!=*

I have tried with "eval" and it may work, but the comparisons are going to be actually used to query a MySQL database (using sqlalchemy) and I'm a bit concerned about the security of that...

Any idea will be deeply appreciated. Thank you!

PS: 
The idea of all this is being able to generate a sqlalchemy query, so if the user inputs the string:
*Product.manufacturer != "foo" || Product.manufacturer != "bar"*

... my tree thing can generate the following:
sqlalchemy.or_(Product.manufacturer !="foo", Product.manufacturer !="bar")

Since sqlalchemy.or_ is callable, I can also store it in one of the leaves... I only see a problem with the "!="

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used SQLAlchemy much, but I'd guess it uses [Python's operator overloading](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) to handle those comparisons. If that's true, then you can use the properties' magic methods. For example:

```
Product.manufacturer == 'bar' => Product.manufacturer.__eq__('bar')
Product.manufacturer != 'foo' => Product.manufacturer.__ne__('foo')
```

You should be able to do a `getattr` on the property object for the appropriate magic method:

```
method_map = {'==': '__eq__', '!=': '__ne__'}
comparison = getattr(Product.manufacturer, method_map[op])   # Here, 'op' is the operator (!=)
sqlalchemy.or_(comparison('foo'), comparison('bar'))         # Equivalent to: Product.manufacturer != 'foo' || Product.manufacturer != 'bar'
```

Hope this helps :)